# Reading input from user without interrupting program execution

Tags: ruby

Im trying to do a loop in ruby that display a number + 1 every second. Id like the user to be able to input when he want. the problem is that i have to input something for the loop to continue. sorry for my bad english im fr

p.s im using a online compiler (repl.it)

Comment: It's possible to do this with Ruby on an Unix terminal, but I doubt you can accomplish it with repl.it, as it requires a more low-level access to the tty interface which (probably) isn't possible through repl.it.

Comment: Another solution is to use Threads. Please provide some sample code and a description of what exactly you want to happen.

Comment: _"Id like the user to be able to input when he want."_ What do you mean? Can you provide an example with some pseudo code?

Comment: im trying to display ex: Number: 1 that will increase by one every second. to do it im using a loop but id like the user to be able to enter an input whenever he wants but i want the number to continue to increase    sorry i have difficulties to explain

Comment: If i try to put the "gets" in the loop, the loop will stop until i input something, but i just want it to ignore the "gets" unless i input something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want using threads and some simple state variables to communicate between the threads.

In this example we use a variable `@stop` to signal from the main thread to the counting thread when it's time to end the counting loop.

This example works on repl.it directly:
https://repl.it/repls/RingedIlliterateEnglishsetter

Hopefully this gives you some ideas on how to proceed.

```
@stop = false

thr = Thread.new {
  puts "Counting thread starting..."
  i = 0

  loop {
    i += 1
    puts i
    sleep 1
    break if @stop
  }

  puts "Counting thread exit..."
}

loop {
  puts "\nWaiting for input...\nType 'stop' to exit..."
  input = gets.chomp

  if input == "stop"
    puts "Stopping..."
    @stop = true
    break
  end
}

# Wait for counting thread to end
thr.join
puts "Main program exit..."
```

Comment: Thanks dude thats what i was looking for. Its impressive how people reply fast on this site :)

Comment: @SamuelFyckes Great :) Remember to approve the answer if it works for you, so others can see it too. Thanks.